# After updating global extension from Spock 1.3 to 2.0 ```start``` is no longer called

Tags: spock

I'm trying to update my extension from Spock 1.3 to 2.0.
It compiles fine and I have changed to implement `IGlobalExtension` instead of extending `AbstractGlobalExtension`. However, after the update `start` and `visitSpec` are no longer called, but `stop` is still called.
What am I missing?

Comment: What you are missing is to post your code here.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not public (yet I hope).

Comment: I found nothing in the migration docs about changes in loading of global extension. But this issue seems related https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1240, it is about the opposite of my issue, i.e. `start` and `stop` called multiple times on Spock 2.0.

Comment: _"Unfortunately the code is not public"_ Forgive me for being blunt, but that is a not a response worthy of a developer. You should know that nobody needs your original code, but simply an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem. Can you debug prose? I cannot. Please learn how to ask good questions. Thank you.